# How to type android robot logo

Tags: android, unicode, fonts

I wanted to know how can we type the android logo and display it.
I went through this link http://osxdaily.com/2009/11/06/how-to-type-the-apple-logo/
But this goes for the apple one and only on a mac OS. Option + Shift + K.
I also downloaded the droid-font and tried copy-pasting it. Doesn work.
How can we do it and display the droid logo icon the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's possible.  Even the Apple logo isn't really possible in any cross-platform way, as you noted.

You might want to read:

- [Wikipedia's article on Unicode Private Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29)
- [The Apple Logo in Unicode](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/unicode_apple_logo.html)

Comment: I tried the apple one on a Mac machine it works fine. I want the same but for an android logo on a windows machine so that people can view the text where ever i post etc etc.

Comment: @dominic Yes, I understand what you want. My answer is that you can't, not as a type-able character. Depending on what you're doing, you can likely use an image, but I'm fairly certain that there is no Android character in any widely-deployed font.

Comment: Any idea how to use the image and display it globally so that it supports all browsers?

Comment: You're doing this in a browser? Yes, an image will work fine! You'll want to learn about the `<img>`tag, among other things.  The [Android Branding Guidelines](http://www.android.com/developers/branding.html) have info on the legality of using the robot image.